# array as arguments in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, arguments

Hello i want to pass array as few arguments in rails.

here is the code i wish to run, but i get to few arguments error

```
query_string = "date_to > ? AND date_from < ?"
var_array = [date_from, date_to]

CreditType.find(type).formulas.where(query_string, var_array.each).exists? // is there a way to loop trought array and pass all elements as arguments?
```

Is this even possible? i tried different kinds of ways, but nothing seems to work, i need this peace of code to be dynamic. `query_string` and `var_arrays` could change. so is there a way to accomplish this? Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass all entries of an array as comma separated params by using the so called splat operator `*` followed by the array.

Try this:

```
 CreditType.find(type).formulas.where(query_string, *var_array).exists?
```